# Add "question with new activity" message to collective page

Tags: feature-request, status-review, collectives, live-refresh

Most of the time when I am trying to answer new R questions I wait at the Questions page with the following tag r. Mostly there pops a message that there is a new question like this (This is nice because you don't have to refresh the page):

[image]

Sometimes people forget to add the r tag to a question which doesn't show when you are following the r tag. So I was wondering if it could be possible to add this message like the above to the r-collective page? Then this message may also work for r-related questions so you only need one page to check for r-related questions and you can directly edit the questions if necessary.